# Equation numbering in Appendix. iopart document class

Tags: appendix

I want the mathematical equations in my Appendices to be numbered as A.1, B.1, C.1.. etc.

However, it is showing as 1.1, 2.1, 3.1.. and so on. How can I remove this error? I am already using packages-

```
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

in `\documentclass[oneside,preprint,12pt,3p]{iopart}`.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use `\numparts`, always use `\begin{subequations}`. That was the issue. Now solved. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain what's the problem with `\numparts`?

Comment: The format for equation numbering in Appendix should be- A.1, A.2... etc. Using \numparts converts the numbering to 1.1, 1.2 etc. So depending upon which format you want, you can choose between \numparts or  \begin{subequations}